# In glsl, how do indices work?

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I have made a vertex shader and fragment shader and kind of know how they work, and I know that you specify what index you want your vertices to be in inside the shader program. So if the vertex was at index 0, does each vertex take up 1 index? If each one took up an index, than how many indices would a matrix 4x4 take up? Sorry if thats confusing but I'm just starting and I don't really know how the indices within the shader works. So:

```
#version 140
in vec3 position; //This could be located at index 0
in mat4 randomMatrix; //If this came right after position, what index is it located at??
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x * 0.5, position.y * 0.5, position.z * 1, 1);
}
```

Tell me if I have this all wrong.

Comment: You are using modern OpenGL so you can manually set uniform locations:

Comment: @SurvivalMachine So are indices 'bytes'? How many indices does a matrix 4x4 take up? Thats the main thing I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL wiki does a pretty good job of [explaining it.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs) I'd recommend specifying the inputs (for readability) with explicit locations:

```
#version 140
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in mat4 randomMatrix;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x * 0.5, position.y * 0.5, position.z * 1, 1);
}
```

Each index essentially takes a vec4, so if you pass a `vec3` in `[x, y, z]`, it's going to get padded internally to `[x, y, z, 0]`. Same with passing a `float`,  it would be padded to `[x, 0, 0, 0]`. A mat4, on the other hand, takes up `4 * vec4` of space, thus it'll take up 4 indices. In your example, if you added one more variable, after the matrix, it would look like this:

```
#version 140
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in mat4 randomMatrix;
layout (location = 5) in float foo;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x * 0.5, position.y * 0.5, position.z * 1, 1);
}
```

The matrix uses attribute indices 1, 2, 3 and 4, one for each collumn.

Comment: Thanks so much "Each index essentially takes a vec4" thats what im looking for! And also, opengl 3.1 doesn't support `layout` I'm pretty sure but I just use `glBindAttribLocation` which is the same.